# How to load xml in to the draw.io diagram?

Tags: xml, diagram, mxgraph, draw.io

How to read an xml file to draw the graph.

my code line below for fetching the XML data like this. I need to all XML data into the `var doc object` for drawing the shape in the diagram

> var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(STYLE_PATH+'/Test.xml');

full code below:

```
mxUtils.getAll([bundle, STYLE_PATH + '/default.xml'], function (xhr) {
                    // Adds bundle text to resources
                    mxResources.parse(xhr[0].getText());

                    // Configures the default graph theme
                    var themes = new Object();
                    themes[Graph.prototype.defaultThemeName] = xhr[1].getDocumentElement();
                    // Main
                    new EditorUi(new Editor(urlParams['chrome'] == '0', themes));
                    var ui = new EditorUi(new Editor());                
                    var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(STYLE_PATH+'/Test.xml');
                    ui.editor.setGraphXml(doc.documentElement);
                }, 

                    function () {
                        document.body.innerHTML = '<center style="margin-top:10%;">Error loading resource files. Please check browser console.</center>';
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue, Now working for me.

```
var ui = new EditorUi(new Editor());
var xml_file_path = STYLE_PATH + '/Test.xml';

            var req = mxUtils.get(xml_file_path, mxUtils.bind(this, function (req) {
                if (req.request.status >= 200 && req.request.status <= 299) {
                    if (req.request.response.length > 0) {
                        editorUi.editor.graph.model.beginUpdate();
                        try {
                            var xmlElem = mxUtils.parseXml(req.request.response).documentElement;
                            editorUi.editor.setGraphXml(xmlElem);

                        }
                        catch (e) {
                            console.error(e);
                        }
                        finally {
                            editorUi.editor.graph.model.endUpdate();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

[mxUtils.parseXml()](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxUtils-js.html#mxUtils.parseXml) expect that you will pass xml string to it, not path to file. So you have to load this file to string and pass that to parseXml.

Comment: I don't have XML string, I have the only XML path so how will do this? Please help me.